# PHP/CSS - Display data in a block

Tags: php, css

I've a question regarding an output of data from MySQL.

basically I have a 3 data per row to be display in my web.

I wanted my output to look like this..

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
----+---+----
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
----+---+----
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
----+---+----
```

the number 1-9 represents my output, which holds the data from my database and I wants the output to display in this format..

-Image
-Title
-Description

Sorry for the long post, I hope you guys can help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your image showing 3 rows with 3 fields or 9 rows as boxes?

Comment: Are you trying to organise the data before it goes to the client (server-side, a [tag:php] question), or present the data to the client once it's there (client-side, and a [tag:css] question)? If it's server-side, please show the PHP you're using; if it's client side then please show the HTML mark-up you've got.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this plugin to do it with css:

http://960.gs/

It is the most commonly used and you don't really need to write your own code for it unless you need more versatility than the plugin provides.

Alertnatively, you can use something like this if you want to write your own code:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table

Answer (score 0):

That's tabular data, you still use  for that.

So if it is a table you wish to use, your problem is how to put it in that order?

You just need to control.

```
$i=0;
$count=mysql_num_rows($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if($i % 3 === 0) {
        if ($i > 0)
             echo "</tr>";
        if ($i < $count - 1)
             echo'<tr>';
    }

    echo '<td style="width: 30%;">'.$i.'</td>';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<table>` to display tabular data.

http://codepad.org/cbLxVe06